# How can i fix this Jquery DataTable issue?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Data is **filled** in Data Table.

1.issue 1: its display "**Showing 1 to 1 of 100**" is wrong.

2.issue 2: when i scroll in data table its not display properly.

1.Note 1: When i press "**f12**" keyboard key issue 1 will be fixed automatically

2.Note 2: When i click on sortable column issue 2 will be fixed automatically

**Image for issue 1**
[image]

**Image for issue 2 "when scroll table it will be like following image"**
[image]

**I have used this code** javascript code

```
function createCompanyDataTable(colsArray, recordPerPage, dataTableDiv) {
    // fetch columnDefs for hide columns based on user preference while initializing datatable
    var columnDefs = fetchColumnDefs(colsArray);
    // fetch column indexes not excluded from the process of hide/show column
    var columnIndexesNotExcludedForColumnVisibility = fetchColumnsNotExcludedForColumnVisibility(colsArray);
    var table = $(dataTableDiv).DataTable({
        /*ajax : dataAjaxUrl,*/
        columns : colsArray,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: 350,
        displayLength: -1,
        scrollX: true,
        deferRender: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        order: [],
        scroller: true,
        dom: 'R<"columns-button"B>ft<"span12"<"span4"><"span4"i><"span4">>',
        // set column default preferences
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        buttons: [
          {
            extend:'colvis',
            className : 'btn btn-primary',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-columns"></i>&nbsp;Columns',
            columns: columnIndexesNotExcludedForColumnVisibility
          },
          {
                 extend: 'collection',
                 text: 'Export',
                 className : 'btn btn-primary export-btn',
                 buttons: [
                           {
                               extend: 'excelHtml5',
                               filename: function(){
                                   var fileName = "Company List By Query" + (companyQueryText==""?"":" - "+companyQueryText); 
                                   return fileName.substring(0,250);
                               },
                               exportOptions: {
                                   columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                               }
                           },
                       ],
          }
        ]
    });
    datatableScrollConfig(table);
    table.on( 'column-visibility.dt', function ( e, settings, column, state ) {
        saveDatatablePreferenceForColumnVisibility($(datatableId).DataTable());
    });
    return table;
}
```

Comment: where is your work? in code

Comment: you can get it from Question